# Display database image on PYQT tablewidgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i tried using the loadfromdata method to get the image from the database, but the image does not show, i think there is something wrong with my implementation

```
  def get_veh_img(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self.veh_img = QLabel('Image')
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self.pixmap.loadFromData(base64.b64decode(self.image), 'jpg')
        self.veh_img.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        return self.veh_img
    
    
        for self.row_id, self.row_data in enumerate(self.vehicle_data):
            self.vehicle_table.insertRow(self.row_id)
            for self.column_id, self.column_data in enumerate(self.row_data):
                if self.column_id == 4:
                    self.img = self.get_veh_img(self.column_data)
                    print(type(self.img))
                    print(type(self.column_data))
    
                    self.vehicle_table.setCellWidget(self.row_id, self.column_id, self.img)
                else:
                    self.vehicle_table.setItem(self.row_id, self.column_id, QTableWidgetItem(str(self.column_data)))
```

what i want to achieve with this code is display an image from the database on a table widget, but wrong now with this code all i get is just a black code, the problem is from the   `self.pixmap.loadFromData(base64.b64decode(self.image), 'jpg'), I think am implementing it wrong, any help, please.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always check if the blob object you are passing to the function is in the correct format before using it.

```
 for self.row_id, self.row_data in enumerate(self.vehicle_data):
                self.vehicle_table.insertRow(self.row_id)
                for self.column_id, self.column_data in enumerate(self.row_data):
                    if self.column_id == 4:
                        pix = QPixmap()
                        self.label = QLabel()
                        if pix.loadFromData(self.column_data):
                            self.label.setPixmap(pix)
                            self.label.setScaledContents(True)
                            self.vehicle_table.setCellWidget(self.row_id, self.column_id, self.label)
                    else:
                        self.vehicle_table.setItem(self.row_id, self.column_id, QTableWidgetItem(str(self.column_data)))
```

instead of creating another function you can just add the loadfromdata up here, i think this code should work for you, you should check the if the image file is in the correct format before proceeding...